# What interfaces are suitable for application coupling?

Tags: c#, c++, rest, soap, com

Currently I'm investigating solutions for making an application usable from other applications. I.e. I want to give other applications control over my application's internals (request current state and other information, trigger actions etc.).

So far I found three viable solutions:

- Provide a COM Server
- Provide a web server with a rest interface
- Provide a SOAP server

Are there any other possibilities that

- rely on standardized technologies
- work with commonly used programming languages and frameworks
- are easy to use (by the consumer as well as me, the developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using a web server with a rest interface would be the easiest option for 3rd parties to connect to your application.

You can also use something like [`Swagger`](http://swagger.io/) to make it even easier for other parties to use your application, since you would be providing a *client* (albeit, raw) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd likely use a rest interface as suggested by npinti, let me show more possibilities:

You can call your application from command line (of course, only from the same machine and account). With a single instance application, this call will be forwarded together with the command line arguments to the running instance, which could then answer that call.

Applications can also communicate via files on a shared location.

Both methods are rather old-style communication methods, and I'd use them only in a legacy context.